# Mapping over a Tree

Tags: haskell, dictionary, tree, fold

I am new to Haskell and for practice I have been implementing a bunch of functions (`map`, `length`, etc) using `foldr` and `foldl`. Now I want to move onto trees!

My tree data structure:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving (Show)
```

I have written a Haskell function to fold over trees:

```
treeFold :: (b->a->b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFold f s (Node a []) = f s a
treeFold f s (Node a xs) = foldl f (f s a) (dFSList xs)
```

where `dFSList` is a list of all the nodes in the tree. So doing something like:

```
treeFold (+) 0 (Node 1 [Node 2 [], Node 3 []])
```

returns 6. Cool.

Now I want to write a Haskell function to map over trees but I want to use my `treeFold` function to do it. Here is what I have so far:

```
treeMap f (Node a []) = (Node (f a) [])
treeMap f (Node a (x:xs)) = (Node (f a) (a list involving foldTree somehow??))
```

How do I finish my `treeMap` function? I want to be able to do

```
treeMap (+1) (Node 1 [Node 2 [], Node 3 []])
```

and it should return

```
(Node 2 [Node 3 [], Node 4 []])
```

Comment: the way you're converting the tree to a flat list (with possibly arbitrary order w.r.t the shape of the tree) and then doing a regular list fold over it means the folding is not tree-specific, i.e. your folding function cannot take into account the shape of the tree and only sees the contents in arbitrary order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to take apart trees generally is with a different variety of fold (often called a catamorphism for some category-theory reason I don't know). You have `data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]`, so to take that apart, you make

```
cat :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
cat f (Node root children) = f root (map (cat f) children)
```

Hokay? So now (using the standard `Functor` class instead of the specialized `treeMap`),

```
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f = cat (Node . f)
```

You can also write linear folds like this. Your `treeFold` confuses me, but you can write, for example,

```
instance Foldable Tree where
  foldMap f = cat go where
    go root children = f root `mappend` fold children
```

Even stronger,

```
instance Traversable Tree where
  traverse f = cat go where
    go root children = Node <$> f root <*> sequenceA children
```

Comment: Interesting. Originally, I wrote something like your cat function but I was bothered by it because I did not think it was very fold like. Nice to know that perhaps that is the only way to go about it

Comment: I believe the term `catamorphism` comes from the same (greek, I guess) prefix `cata-` as in `catastrophe`, meaning "destruct, taking apart", as you wrote above. `Morphism` means shape-changing, transformation. So a `catamorphism` is just a "transformation which takes apart".

Comment: @ilikecats The "Church encoding" which represents a data structure as a function looks like this: (1) for every option in the data structure (separated by `|`), create a function from those arguments to some unknown `b`; (2) when you see a recursion of the data structure, accept a `b` as an argument instead; (3) make a function from those argument-functions to said `b`.  So `Either x y` becomes the fold `(x -> b) -> (y -> b) -> b`; `data BinLeaf x y = Bin x (Tree x y) (Tree x y) | Leaf y` becomes the fold `(x -> b -> b -> b) -> (y -> b) -> b`, etc.

Comment: @ChrisDrost I am not going to lie, Chris. I am a little bit confused here. Looking at 1, I see that I would want to create a function for every option separated by | . But my data structure is not separated in such a way. Can you elaborate by what you mean?

Comment: @ilikecats: if you don't have multiple constructors then there will only be one argument-function, like `data Pair x = Pair x x` is Church-encoded to `(x -> x -> b) -> b`, or `(Int, String, Integer)` is Church-encoded to `(Int -> String -> Integer -> b) -> b`. In your case your data structure was `data Tree x = Node x [Tree x]` so its Church encoding is `(x -> [b] -> b) -> b`. But for example `data Bool = True | False` gets encoded as `(() -> b) -> (() -> b) -> b` which can be reduced to `b -> b -> b`; `data Maybe x = Nothing | Just x` gets encoded as `b -> (x -> b) -> b`, and so forth.

Comment: In case it's not clear, I'm trying to explain why `cat :: (x -> [b] -> b) -> Tree x -> b` is in some sense the "correct fold function" by explaining that `flip cat tree` is a function `(x -> [b] -> b) -> b` which is exactly equivalent to `tree`: everything that one can do, the other can do. Your `treeFold` was problematic because it was trying to model this as `b -> (b -> a -> b) -> b` which we can recognize as just the `[a]` type, in other words your `treeFold` was the function `toList = foldMap (:[]) :: (Foldable t) => t x -> [x]` which nukes the structure of the tree by "flattening" it.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `treeFold` to write something like `treeMap`.

```
treeMap f (Node a xs) = Node (f a) (map (treeMap f) xs)
```

The base classes that correspond to the same ideas are `Foldable` and `Functor`. Everything in base that is `Foldable` is already a `Functor`; it's natural to be able to define `treeMap` independently of `treeFold`.

Comment: What if I wanted to though? Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I don't think you can with your definition of `treeFold`. It loses all of the tree structure when you call `dFSList` on the branches.